# Found extra positional argument package error on Sencha Touch build command

Tags: android, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I am using Sencha  touch 2.4.2  and Sencha Cmd is 6.0.2.
I am using command

**sencha app build package**

I am getting following error on build
Sencha Cmd v6.0.2.14

[ERR] Found extra positional argument package

This question is already asked on
https://de.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?305473-Error-when-running-sencha-app-build-package&p=1116961&viewfull=1&langid=14

But there is no any answer .

On issuing Below help Command

**sencha help app build**

lists following

**sencha app build [production|testing|native|package]**

I am issuing same command but there is error

Any help please .

Answer (score 2):

You should run it without name first for "sencha app build", then can continue for platforms. I guess it already makes each platforms which mentioned in config file. So do not need to build each platform. just execute sencha app build and emulate it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Redirect into your project folder Example: **D:\Test\CordovaWithSencha\sencha app build**  -press enter key.
now your project will build successfully.
For running your application follow same command as **D:\Test\CordovaWithSencha\sencha app run** -press enter.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is quite old:

options need to come before the environment. So:

`sencha app build --destination mydest production`

works.

Its somewhat hidden in the help in the last line:

`Syntax
   sencha app build [options] [theme|locale|build]... [environment]`

Answer (score 0):

The command has been changed from "sencha app build package" to "sencha build package"