# Android folder doesn't created inside cordova platform folder

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

To create cross platform android app by refer the following URL, [Sencha tool for create android app](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/tutorials/cordova_camera.html)

as i follow the steps but the android folder doesn't created inside the cordova platform folder if that is created then only i can proceed the step 8 in that url anybody can help me how to overcome that issue thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After step 4, you may have to execute "cordova platform add android" command to create android platform folder if its missed out.

Comment: Yes tha't work correct but now i got error error found extra positional argument android and it's skip from command line

Comment: @SeeniVasan, could you please elaborate? Any error trace?

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/5238158/gandhi,                           These are my command prompt statements                        D:\soft\touch-2.4.2\cam>sencha app build android
Sencha Cmd v6.1.1.76
[ERR] Found extra positional argument android                                                                       and error i'm repeatedly try more than 10 times same error occured

Comment: @SeeniVasan have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125373/found-extra-positional-argument-package-error-on-sencha-touch-build-command Hope it helps